# Derivative of divergent summation

Tags: derivatives

I like to know derivative of below formula.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{n}$$
But i thinks it is hard to me so i like to know approximate formula.

Is there anyone who knows what i want to know ?

Comment: I know only what I want to know.

Comment: $\frac{d \sum_{n=1}^x 1/n}{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\delta(x-n)}{n}$

Comment: You are searching some formula or approximation for harmonic numbers (or generalized harmonic numbers)? See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: For large $x$ your function behaves asymptotically like this
$$\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{n} = \ln x + \gamma + \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{12x^2} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

Comment: Since the $x$th harmonic number $H_x = \gamma + \psi(x+1)$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function, we have $H_x' = \psi'(x+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is, for now, ill defined. You have to tell what set $x$ belongs to, and you basically have two options:

1. $x\in\mathbb N$: This is the standard setting for the summation symbol, as usually, an expression like $$\sum_{n=1}^\pi \frac1n$$ is not really encountered. This is because $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$
   is defined as: $S_1 = a_1$, $S_N = a_N + S_{N-1}$ for $N>1$, and in this definition, $N$ is assumed to be an integer. The problem with using this definition for your purposes, however, is that derivatives of functions of integers are not defined.
2. If you define $\sum_{n=1}^x$ as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}\frac1n$$ (in which case the sum from $1$ to $\pi$ is equal to the sum from $1$ to $3$, then your function is piecewise constant, and the derivative is $0$ everywhere but on the integers (where there is no derivative).

---

*Bottom line*:

Your derivative is either trivial to calculate and is almost everywhere $0$, or your question doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This can be interpreted as a question for [summability calculus](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5739.pdf). In this context, the expression is well defined. The linked document gives you all the formalism you need to get the correct result.